# Vue.js and VueRouter slow performance

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

i got SPA web page using Vue.js and routing with VueRouter.

For example i got 2 pages:

- On first i got list of entities, each of them are the same `Components` with some amount of data in it to display information to customers, with pagination on this page `(1)`,
- On second got profile info `(2)`.

Transition `(1) => (2)` with `entities = [];` are fast, but when this list is not empty, this transition becomes real slow, and it depends of `entities.length`.

What is happening?

1. Click to `(2)`;
2. `router.beforeEach` handler triggers momentally;
3. `(2).beforeMount` triggers;
4. `(1).beforeDestroy` triggers;
5. Big delay;
6. `(1).destroyed` triggers;
7. `(2).mounted` triggers and `(2)` visually load.

In `step 5` i got

```
beforeDestroy() {
    console.time(this.entity.id);
},
destroyed() {
    console.timeEnd(this.entity.id);
}
```

and it gives this

on `entities.length == 20` we got console output like:

[image]

on `entities.length == 60` we got console output like:

[image]

This `beforeDestroy => destroyed` time gap in each `Entity` depends of `entities.length` and tends to zero, after `Entity` being destroyed, next `beforeDestroy => destroyed` time gap is getting less time.

Each `Entity` inside doesn't know about other `Entities`.

What i did wrong and how to fix or workaround this problem? Maybe i miss something about Vue.js lifecycle.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: Do you have unique `:key` params for every `Entity` component?

Comment: Yes, sure, without ```:key``` prop Vue throw a warning message.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Damian, yes, the problem was in slow 'computed's in each iterable component, try to solve this with sequential detach some 'computed's in component and look for the performance.